# Need to display an array to a MessageBox with rows of Assignment Names and columns of Student Names

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I need to display a transposed array of student grades on assignments to a MessageBox. I have the transposed array part down, but I need the messagebox to have row and column labels.

Right now the output MessageBox only shows a 3 rows by 5 columns matrix of grades:

```
    decimal[,] decGrades = { { 87m, 88m, 89m },
                             { 90m, 95m, 100m },
                             { 70m, 80m, 90m },
                             { 50m, 50m, 50m },
                             { 80m, 92m, 94m } };

        string[] strStudentNames = { "Adams", "Benson", "Carson", 
  "Daley", "Edwards" };
        string[] strAssignmentNames = { "HW1", "HW2", "Exam1" };




    private decimal[,] TransposeMatrix(decimal[,] newArray)
    {
        decimal[,] TransposedArray = new decimal[newArray.GetLength(1), 
    newArray.GetLength(0)];
        for (int column = 0; column < newArray.GetLength(1); column++)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < newArray.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                TransposedArray[column, row] = newArray[row, column];

            }
        }
        return TransposedArray;
    }




    private void BtnTranspose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decGrades = TransposeMatrix(decGrades);

        ////CODE TO SEND GRADES ARRAY TO MESSAGE BOX
        string gradesString = "";



        for (int i = 0; i < decGrades.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < decGrades.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                gradesString += decGrades[i, j] + " ";
            }

            gradesString += "\n";
        }

        MessageBox.Show(gradesString, "Transposed Array");
```

I can't seem to figure out how to display the string array values in strStudentNames as column labels and strAssignmentNames as the row labels.

I really appreciate any help I could get on this. Thanks!

Comment: MessageBox is not an appropriate UI element for tabular data. It's not designed for that. It's designed for conveying status messages, such as errors and task completion. You need to create your own form that can display the data in a DataGridView or similar control and show it as a modal dialog.

Comment: And you can style your custom form with datagridview to look as MessageBox with rows and columns ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
private void BtnTranspose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var matrix = TransposeMatrix(decGrades);

  // Create a form
  var form = new Form();
  form.Text = "Transposed Array";
  form.Size = new Size(500, 400);
  form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

  // Create a list view
  var listview = new ListView();
  listview.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  listview.View = View.Details;
  listview.FullRowSelect = true;

  // Initialize columns titles with first empty
  listview.Columns.Add("");
  for ( int indexD2 = 0; indexD2 < matrix.GetLength(1); indexD2++ )
    listview.Columns.Add(strStudentNames[indexD2]);

  // Add rows with first column as title
  for ( int indexD1 = 0; indexD1 < matrix.GetLength(0); indexD1++ )
  {
    var item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = strAssignmentNames[indexD1];
    for ( int indexD2 = 0; indexD2 < matrix.GetLength(1); indexD2++ )
      item.SubItems.Add(matrix[indexD1, indexD2].ToString());
    listview.Items.Add(item);
  }

  // Add the list view to the form and show it
  form.Controls.Add(listview);
  form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Instead of creating an on-the-fly form, you can create a custom form by design with a close button at bottom to have a true message box. You will add a method that takes the matrix as parameter and put the code in this method:

```
public partial MyMessageBox : Form
{
  static public Run(decimal[,] matrix, string[] titleColumns, string[] titleRows)
  {
    if ( titleColumns.Length != matrix.GetLength(1) 
      || titleRows.Length != matrix.GetLength(0) )
      throw new ArgumentException("Bounds mismatch");
    var form = new MyMessageBox();
    form.ListView.Columns.Add("");
    for ( int indexD2 = 0; indexD2 < matrix.GetLength(1); indexD2++ )
      form.ListView.Columns.Add(titleColumns[indexD2]);
    for ( int indexD1 = 0; indexD1 < matrix.GetLength(0); indexD1++ )
    {
      var item = new ListViewItem();
      item.Text = titleRows[indexD1];
      for ( int indexD2 = 0; indexD2 < matrix.GetLength(1); indexD2++ )
        item.SubItems.Add(matrix[indexD1, indexD2].ToString());
      form.ListView.Items.Add(item);
    }
    form.ShowDialog();  
  }
}
```

So you will use it like that:

```
private void BtnTranspose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyMessageBox.Run(TransposeMatrix(decGrades), strStudentNames, strAssignmentNames);
}
```